# How to extend the duration of an rx Observable.timer?

Tags: rxjs

Given an `Observable.timer(10000)`. Say, that I'd like to continuously update the timer and not allow it to emit, is it possible?

For example, at t = 2000, I want to increase the timeout time by 2000. Given this dynamic code change, the timer will now emit at t = 12000 rather than the original t = 10000.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below.

```js
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document,"click")
.scan((curr,acc)=>++curr,0)
.flatMap(e=>{
console.log(e)
return Rx.Observable.timer(e*1000)}
)
.subscribe(console.log)
```